# Excel comparing 3 columns against golden results/

Tags: excel, compare

I have been trying with little success to compare four columns containing url results to a golden list in excel.

I want to count all the matches in each column and give a running total per set. I have used **VLOOKUP**, Match and highlight duplicates none seem to be able to give the desired effect

```
Golden list   Column A    Column B     Column C     Column D
```

I want it to compare the values in the golden list against the other 4 columns and give a score count of all exact matches found. I have read several of the **Excel Stack Overflow** questions and used youtube with no luck so far.

Comment: What is an example input? What desired output? Do you want to assign each row from `golden list` a score 0-4, how many times the entry is present in other columns? Or a score for each `column`, how many of entries from this column match against `golden list`?

Comment: My Example input is URL addresses from websites. I desire to have the number of matches in each column found (compared against the golden standard) There is 100 items per column so between 0 - 100 would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computing score for each item in golden list is as easy as:

```
=COUNTIF(range_of_all_columns, item_from_golden_list)
```

To get the score for each column you can either:

- match each item in each column individually or
- match each item in golden list against all of the columns respectively (if exact matches are sufficient)

For the second approach, you can use `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(...)), 1, 0)` approach - if you have duplicated links in columns, or a simpler formula if they are unique:

```
=COUNTIF(range_of_1_column, item_from_golden_list)
```

..and then sum it all up for each column, as illustrated by following picture:

[image: excel printscreen as an answer illustration]

Comment: Sorry to be a donkey but can't really follow it. I have the Golden list values input -- where did this Golden score come from / Coulmn score do I need to put them in ?  why are Column A-D below should not be alongside and where do I put these functions in.....

Comment: it's an illustration since you did not provide any example input. you can ignore `Golden score` altogether and move other ranges around as long as `Column score` has equal number of rows as item in golden list - for more basic Excel advice there are countless tutorials about ranges which are out of scope of this programming question i believe, e.g. see how [`COUNTIF`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx) works

Comment: Thanks you very much been awesomely helpful !